# Second moment of area of a rod (not circular cross section)

Tags: stress-strain, moment-of-inertia

I'm trying to calculate the stress induced in a rod by an end mass with an initial rate of rotation. My current idea to calculate this is:

1) Calculate the [rotational stiffness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiffness#Rotational_stiffness)  of the rod

2) Calculate the moment of induced in the rod by the rotating mass in a small subsection of time (dt)

3) Calculate bending stress using this equation;

[image]

However I'm unsure if I can easily apply this equation to the rod in my problem as the axis of the moment is along the length of the rod (as opposed to orthogonal from it). My hope is that I can calculate the second moment of area of the side of the rod and hence the moment will be orthogonal to the axis of the rod. However I'm still not sure if I can do this as I'm talking about the side view of the rod, so although I have the length and diameter, does the fact the surface is curved have an effect?

Comment: Do you have the elasticity tensor of the rod?

Comment: No. Does elasticity impact the stiffness?

Comment: Stiffness arises from the elasticity tensor, but never mind then. You say in 1) that you could calculate the rotational stiffness - how would you do this?

Comment: I just noticed that your rod has a non-circular cross section. You may find this very difficult to model analytically. I would recommend getting your hands dirty with some [finite element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) software. There are some free ones out there.

Comment: When I say the surface is curved, I mean side view of a cylinder is essentially a rectangle, and I'm unsure if I can use the equations for a rectangle as the side is curved. Also the wiki link for rotational stiffness gives an equation for calculating the rotational stiffness. This requires J, which is the second moment of area of the rod, but the axis of this is along the length of the rod, so this is a different value than required for the bending moment-stress section.